# Dojo datagrid not shown on deselected tabbar

Tags: datagrid, dojo, tabbar

I have two tabbar (dojox.mobile.TabBarButton) where I put custom widget on each tab. On the second tab, the widget uses datagrid to display JSON data. This is where I faced a problem. The data for the datagrid is being loaded correctly and the DOM node is formed as well, but the datagrid itself is not shown. Yet it works wonder when I put it on the first tab. Here is my JS code.

```
var gridDataUrl = "gridData.json";
var params = {
    url: gridDataUrl,
    handleAs: "json"
};

var resultGridNode = this.resultGridNode;

dojo.xhrGet(params).then(function(response){
    var gridData = response;
    var data = {
        label: gridData.identifier,
        identifier: gridData.identifier,
        items: gridData.items
    };

    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data: data
    });

    var dg = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        id: "grid",
        store: store,
        structure: gridData.structure
    }, resultGridNode);

    dg.resize();
    dg.startup();
});
```

The custom template:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="resultGridNode" style="height: 600px; width: 400px">
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent template where I attached my widget:

```
<div id="tabView1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" data-dojo-props="selected: true" style="height: 100%;">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Result</h1>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRect" style="height: 100%" class="mblRoundRect">
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="resultgrid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After debugging, I found out that the problem might be the resize method from the view. When the datagrid is put on the deselected tabbar, the width and height are set to 0. Calling resize method explicitly doesn't have any effects. Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

What is a tabbar, `dijit.layout.TabContainer`?

Why is the grid in a `dijit.layout.BorderContainer`?  Using a `BorderContainer` with a height of 100% will not work unless all the parent dom nodes have a height of 100%.  I'd would remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a detail. I've edited my post. Tabbar is dojox.mobile.TabBarButton. I had to use dijit.layout.BorderContainer in my custom template, otherwise the datagrid wouldn't get diplayed. Probably have something to do with the company's framework I'm using.